# TShark: Capture stops prematurely when using ring buffer (-b) and printing to stdout (-P)

Tags: tshark

**EDIT:**
I have found a workaround. Using `-b duration:[seconds]` instead of `-b filesize:[size]` works for whatever reason. Example:

```
tshark -i lo -l -b files:10 -b duration:5 -w /tmp/pingtest.pcap -P
```

--End Edit--

I am trying to run TShark (v3.4.4 on Ubuntu 21.04) continuously to capture specific fields with -T fields (so dumpcap is out of the question) and print to stdout for piping to a Python script. Using ring buffer helps with the common out of memory issue, but presents another issue for me. After rotating off the first file, TShark just stops capturing without throwing any error messages.

For example, simply:

```
tshark -i lo -l -b files:10 -b filesize:5 -w /tmp/pingtest.pcap -P
```

Followed by (in another terminal):

```
ping -c 100 127.0.0.1
```

Results in my TShark capture stopping after only 35 packets:

```
   33 16.384242495    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0003, seq=24/6144, ttl=64
   34 16.384250425    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    ICMP 98 Echo (ping) reply    id=0x0003, seq=24/6144, ttl=64 (request in 33)
   35 17.425021635    127.0.0.1 → 127.0.0.1    ICMP 98 Echo (ping) request  id=0x0003, seq=25/6400, ttl=64
35 packets captured
```

Removing the -P option from the command solves this issue, but -P is necessary for my script. Reading [online](https://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-users/201301/msg00034.html), this is a known issue that TShark might not be able to keep up with the rate that dumpcap is writing to the file. However, this does not make sense in this scenario as the pings are coming in extremely slowly.

Thank you for any comments and answers.